# Exportar a CSV crea una linea por caracter y no por cada miembro de la lista

Tags: python, csv

Intento crear un archivo csv desde una lista en python, pero no me lo hace correctamente.

En lugar de añadir cada elemento de la lista, me añade cada carácter de la lista en una fila nueva y no entiendo por qué.

Este es el código:

```
with open('equipos', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(equipos)
```

Este es el contendio de la lista equipos que quiero exportar:

```
['Sp Gijon', 'Barcelona', 'Oviedo', 'La Coruna', 'Lerida', 'Logrones', 'Valladolid', 'Real Madrid', 'Ath Madrid', 'Celta', 'Osasuna', 'Sevilla', 'Vallecano', 'Albacete', 'Sociedad', 'Valencia', 'Ath Bilbao', 'Zaragoza', 'Santander', 'Tenerife']
```

Pero el resultado es un csv donde en cada fila nueva tengo una letra, y lo que yo quiero es un equipo por fila. Alguna pista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**csvwriter.writerow(row)**

> Escribe el parámetro row al objeto de archivo del writer, formateado
> según el dialecto actual. Retorna el valor de retorno de la llamada al
> método write del objeto de archivo subyacente.
>
> Distinto en la versión 3.5: Agregado soporte para iterables.

**csvwriter.writerows(rows)**

> Escribe todos los elementos en rows (un iterable de objetos row como
> se describe anteriormente) al objeto de archivo del writer,
> formateados según el dialecto actual.

El método `writerows` está implementado usando `writerow`, más o menos asi:

```
def writerows(self, rows):
    for row in rows:
        self.writerow(row)
```

Si probamos a grabar una cadena con `writerow`

```
with open('equipos', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow("la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta")
```

obtenemos el siguiente archivo:

```
l,a, ,m,o,n,a, ,j,a,c,i,n,t,a, ,s,e, ,h,a, ,p,u,e,s,t,o, ,u,n,a, ,c,i,n,t,a
```

**Intepretación**

El método `writerow` espera un iterable y graba todos sus elementos separados por coma. Una cadena es un iterable. Sus elementos son los caracteres.

El método `writerows` recorre la lista de equipos aplicando `writerow` a cada equipo. Cada equipo es una cadena y el resultado que obtienes se ajusta a la especificación.

**Solución**

La solución es poner `equipos` dentro de otra lista:

```
with open('equipos', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows([equipos])
```

¿Qué pasa ahora? `writerows` recibe una lista con un solo elemento (`equipos`). Itera sobre esta lista obteniendo su único elemento `['Sp Gijon', 'Barcelona', ..]`, el que pasa a `writerow`.

El método `writerow` itera sobre la lista recibida, recuperando y grabando los elementos, que ahora son cadenas completas.

El resultado:

```
Sp Gijon,Barcelona,Oviedo,La Coruna,Lerida,Logrones,Valladolid,Real Madrid,Ath M
adrid,Celta,Osasuna,Sevilla,Vallecano,Albacete,Sociedad,Valencia,Ath Bilbao,Zara
goza,Santander,Tenerife
```

**Edición**

Código para grabar un equipo por línea (no .CSV)

```
with open('equipos', 'w') as f:
    for equipo in equipos:
        f.write(f"{equipo}\n")
```

Comment: Sólo hay un pequeño detalle que no hace bien. Antes cada letra era una fila. Ahora mete cada uno de los equipos en la misma fila. Cómo se podría hacer para que cada equipo vaya a una columna distinta?

Comment: @RobertoGimenez. Si cada equipo va en una línea distinta, ya no sería un CSV, pues no hay ningún coma en ningún lugar. Se trataría de un archivo plano puro y simple. Edite la respuesta para incluir ese caso